# JVM Eager loading options

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there is is any option in SUN (Oracle) JVM to enable eager loading of classes. Like IBM JVM has option -Dibm.cl.eagerresolution

I want to use reflection in my code and was thinking that eager loading of the classes might reduce the lookup time while instantiating object using reflection.

Please suggest if eager loading will be benefit when using reflection.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599602/eager-java-class-loading below link might help you http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPClassLoading.fm.html